# Binary to Hexadecimal Conversions

Tags: python-2.7, binary, hex

```
#Conversion from Hex to Bin
def gethex(hexadecimal1):
       numbintotal=' '
       for i in range(len(hexadecimal1)):              
              numbin1=hexadecimal1[i]
              if(numbin1=='0'):
                  result='0000'
              elif(numbin1=='1'):
                  result='0001'
              elif(numbin1=='2'):
                   result='0010'
              elif(numbin1=='3'):
                   result='0011'
              elif(numbin1=='4'):
                   result='0100'
              elif(numbin1=='5'):
                  result='0101'
              elif(numbin1=='6'):
                   result='0110'
              elif(numbin1=='7'):
                   result='0111'
              elif(numbin1=='8'):
                   result='1000'
              elif(numbin1=='9'):
                   result='1001'
              elif(numbin1=='a'):
                   result='1010'
              elif(numbin1=='b'):
                   result='1011'
              elif(numbin1=='c'):
                   result='1100'
              elif(numbin1=='d'):
                   result='1101'
              elif(numbin1=='e'):
                   result='1110'
              elif(numbin1=='f'):
                   result='1111'
              elif(numbin1=='q'):
#Get hexadecimal
while(numhex!='q'):
    numhex=raw_input('Enter a hexadecimal number (q to quit): ')
    numbin= gethex(numhex)
    if(numhex=='q'):
        print(numbin)
    else:
        print('The binary number is:'+ numbin)


                   result='Program shutting down...'
              else:
                   result='Please type in a hexadecimal number'
              numbintotal= numbintotal + result
       return numbintotal


#Create a varaible
numhex='0'
results='0'
numbin1='0'
```

I get how to covert from Hexadecimal to Binary as shown above, but I am not to sure how to do it the other way around of doing Binary to Hex? Please note that you cannot use any of the Python functions as that will be just an easy way out so I'm just letting you know that! I was thinking doing the exact opposite of in the code so, for example numbin1== 0001 and result= 1. Please help me out that would extremely appreciated! THIS IS IN PYTHON 2.7!

Answer (score 0):

Try this function out.

```
def binhexZ(invalue):
    wmap = {"0000": "0",
            "0001": "1",
            "0010": "2",
            "0011": "3",
            "0100": "4",
            "0101": "5",
            "0110": "6",
            "0111": "7",
            "1000": "8",
            "1001": "9",
            "1010": "A",
            "1011": "B",
            "1100": "C",
            "1101": "D",
            "1110": "E",
            "1111": "F"
            }
    i = 0
    output = ""

    while (len(invalue) % 4 != 0):
        invalue = "0" + invalue

    while (i < len(invalue)):
        output = output + wmap[invalue[i:i + 4]]
        i = i + 4

    output = output.lstrip("0")
    output = "0" if len(output) == 0 else output

    return output
```